# How can I hide printers attached to a specific server in Windows "Add printer" dialog?

Tags: windows-7, samba, network-printer

We have a lot of Windows 7 Clients a Samba 3 DC. When a user would like to add a printer the list is populated with all printers shared by all servers on the network. However, we would like to limit the printers in the list to a specific server.

[image: This is what the dialog looks now:]

We would like to hide e. g. printers attached to `ARIAL` and `BODONI`.

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: It would be easy with GP, if it was an AD domain. Also, users wouldn't need to install any printers by themselves.

Comment: @EsaJokinen: what would be the solution using GPs (the limitation part)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by blocking access to TCP ports 139 and 445 on the mentioned hosts in t.

Comment: umm... this will remove all share file access and not only printer access, correct? why not just... not share the printers?

Comment: I know, it is complicated. It is kind of a transition phase in which the old clients use the old setup until they are replaced by new clients over the course of the next year. Not really satisfying for me either.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Group Policy you can do this by limiting the number of each type of printer listed in the Add Printer Wizard. If you don't have Group Policy then you'll need to do this on each printer or server by disabling the mechanisms by which a printer can be discovered, such as:

SNMP

Bluetooth

WS-Discovery

Bonjour

File and Printer Sharing

Comment: To me it is still not clear on how to limit the options in the "Add printer" dialog. The Point-and-Print-GP does not work. Of course I can choose to publish only certain printers in AD.